# Python Properly replace some content from Variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to scraping using Yahoo Engine. Using keyword like "python".

I have wrote this little program :

```
query = "python"
url = {"https://fr.search.yahoo.com/search?p=&fr=yfp-search-sb",
"https://fr.search.yahoo.com/search?p=&fr=yfp-search-sb&b=11&pz=10&pstart=5"}

def checker():
    for yahoo in url:
        yahooo = yahoo.replace("&fr",query + "&fr") 
    r = requests.get(yahooo)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    links =  soup.find_all('a')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        a = link.get('href')
        unquote(a)
        print("Urls : " + a)
        with open("Yahoo.txt", mode="a",encoding="utf-8") as fullz:
            fullz.write(a + "\n")
            fullz.close()
        lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
        outfile = open("Yahoonodup.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
        for line in open("Yahoo.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8"):
            if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate                               
                outfile.write(line)
                lines_seen.add(line)
        outfile.close()
            
checker()
```

My output file contains some urls like this :

```
https://r.search.yahoo.com/cbclk2/dWU9MURCNjczQ0UwNThBNDk4MyZ1dD0xNjE2ODAzMTA5MDE4JnVvPTg0OTM3NTA2NTgyMzY5Jmx0PTImcz0xJmVzPVdHbFZxQzRHUFNfemNveGNLaUgxVkpoX3lXV2N2WFhiQkRfZklRLS0-/RV=2/RE=1616831909/RO=10/RU=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2faclick%3fld%3de8BWTO-5A13W9y2D2Aw39AjjVUCUyb98EJf6bSa7R7dGxGXelKfNh7KW94OonXABpN7Bo9YkZqB22Evk3cfTIpJi3aGEXXKJMtDqnaNUDUVcsehzFOYyr09GoYqUE-iUywRWeOnV4aeACKf4_YX6dE2BVZAbqkvWj4HQMqeB_Fl1KlwT1v%26u%3daHR0cHMlM2ElMmYlMmZ2ZXJnbGVpY2guZm9jdXMuZGUlMmZ3YXNjaG1hc2NoaW5lJTJmJTNmY2hhbm5lbCUzZGJpbmclMjZkZXZpY2UlM2RjJTI2bmV0d29yayUzZG8lMjZjYW1wYWlnbiUzZDQwNzE4NzU1MCUyNmFkZ3JvdXAlM2QxMzU4OTk2OTA3NDAxNDE4JTI2dGFyZ2V0JTNka3dkLTg0OTM3NjAxMjIzNjUyJTNhbG9jLTcyJTI2YWQlM2Q4NDkzNzUwNjU4MjM2OSUyNmFkLWV4dGVuc2lvbiUzZA%26rlid%3d0fc40f09a4b6109e9c726f57d193ec0e/RK=2/RS=3w4U9AT_OQyaVSF.6KLwzWuo_LU-;_ylc=cnQDMQ--?IG=0ac9439bcf3f4ec087000000005bf464
```

And I want to change it into the real links :

```
https://vergleich.focus.de/waschmaschine/?channel=bing&device=c&network=o&campaign=407187550&adgroup=1358996907401418&target=kwd-84937601223652:loc-72&ad=84937506582369&ad-extension=
```

It's possible ?

Comment: What content is "not desired"?  How would one distinguish between what is desired and what isn't?

Comment: What do you mean by `using keyword like "python"`?

Comment: how can you concatenate all the urls together and then hoping fecthing the results in a single query? instead use some threadpoolexecutor or fetch them one at a time

Comment: Sorry i have update my code. For the keyword. 
What did you mean DevLounge could you show me ?

Comment: Scott Hunter try to run my program you will se there is a lots of urls thats appears like `https://r.search.yahoo.com/........` That seems to be encrypted is i'm true ?

Comment: I still don't understand. Why don't you think these URLs should appear in your file? You're asking for every link on the web page, right? Well, those links are on the web page - you will be able to see this if you use a web browser and view the page source. If you only want some of the links, then first you have to think of a rule that tells you which links you want and which links you don't want. I also don't understand what you mean by '"seem to be encrypted". In the real world, URLs are often complex and contain stuff that you can't easily make sense of. It's still meaningful to the server.

Comment: @Akyna - Regardless of what that stuff is in those URLs, those are still the URLs.  If  you want to go on and use the URLs you have scraped, you don't want to remove any part of them...certainly not any part of the path component of the URL.  What you might want to do is exclude certain URLs based on some pattern, but you'd then need to describe in your code what that pattern is.  Otherwise, don't worry about the exact form that the URLs take.  Just use them in whatever form they take.

Comment: Okay thanks for you're answer i will think about it. I just want to get link from like this url : https://fr.search.yahoo.com/search?p=test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-url-python-requests/) the response will return the url of the site that was responsible of returning the content. Meaning that for your example, you can do something like this.

```
url = 'https://r.search.yahoo.com/cbclk2/dWU9MURCNjczQ0UwNThBNDk4MyZ1dD0xNjE2ODAzMTA5MDE4JnVvPTg0OTM3NTA2NTgyMzY5Jmx0PTImcz0xJmVzPVdHbFZxQzRHUFNfemNveGNLaUgxVkpoX3lXV2N2WFhiQkRfZklRLS0-/RV=2/RE=1616831909/RO=10/RU=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2faclick%3fld%3de8BWTO-5A13W9y2D2Aw39AjjVUCUyb98EJf6bSa7R7dGxGXelKfNh7KW94OonXABpN7Bo9YkZqB22Evk3cfTIpJi3aGEXXKJMtDqnaNUDUVcsehzFOYyr09GoYqUE-iUywRWeOnV4aeACKf4_YX6dE2BVZAbqkvWj4HQMqeB_Fl1KlwT1v%26u%3daHR0cHMlM2ElMmYlMmZ2ZXJnbGVpY2guZm9jdXMuZGUlMmZ3YXNjaG1hc2NoaW5lJTJmJTNmY2hhbm5lbCUzZGJpbmclMjZkZXZpY2UlM2RjJTI2bmV0d29yayUzZG8lMjZjYW1wYWlnbiUzZDQwNzE4NzU1MCUyNmFkZ3JvdXAlM2QxMzU4OTk2OTA3NDAxNDE4JTI2dGFyZ2V0JTNka3dkLTg0OTM3NjAxMjIzNjUyJTNhbG9jLTcyJTI2YWQlM2Q4NDkzNzUwNjU4MjM2OSUyNmFkLWV4dGVuc2lvbiUzZA%26rlid%3d0fc40f09a4b6109e9c726f57d193ec0e/RK=2/RS=3w4U9AT_OQyaVSF.6KLwzWuo_LU-;_ylc=cnQDMQ--?IG=0ac9439bcf3f4ec087000000005bf464'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.url) ## this will give you 'https://vergleich.focus.de/waschmaschine/?channel=bing&device=c&network=o&campaign=407187550&adgroup=1358996907401418&target=kwd-84937601223652:loc-72&ad=84937506582369&ad-extension='
```

Comment: Yes this maybe fix my problem. That's the only i have you think ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here 'That's the only I have you think ?', but from my understanding of what you're trying to do, this should work for you. Just read the file line by line and replace the the URL variable with the URL's from your text file.

Comment: I can using `url=a` for requests all my resultat for made like a double check ?